# Hermite polynomials orthogonal to ${1 \over \sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Given the hermite polynomials $H_0(t) = 1, H_1(t) = -t, H_2(t) = {1 \over\sqrt2} (t^2 - 1) \ ..., $ my lecture notes claim that

$$\int_{\Bbb R} H_i(t)H_j(t) {1 \over \sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2} = 1(i = j).$$

Is there any way to see this easily?

Comment: You need to use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula

Comment: You need to apply integration by parts several times to get the result.